# how can I add git submodule into git repo as normal directory?

Tags: git, dockerfile, jenkins-scriptler

**Let's see what it is**

- Create two git repo `sub` & `test`

```
mkdir test sub
cd test && git init && touch README && git add README && git commit -m "initialize the git repo" && cd ..
cd sub && git init && touch README && git add README && git commit -m "initialize the sub git repo" && cd ..
```

- Move the `sub` repo into `test`

```
mv sub test
cd test 
git add sub
git commit -m "add sub directory"
```

I want to treat them as one git repo and push them remotely, but now the files under `sub` directory can not be included ?

How can I achieve this in simple way like treat sub as normal directory ?

**Use case for this**

I try to add my jenkins data folder (`JENKINS_HOME`) into docker images using `Dockerfile` for demo. (`ADD JEKINS_HOME /opt/jenkins`)

```
JENKINS_HOME
Dockerfile
```

My jenkin has [scriptler plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Scriptler+Plugin) which contains the git repo for its purpose. Then it exists in my docker image git repo like below

```
$ find jenkins-docker
./.git
./.git/.. (skipped
./Dockerfile
./JENKINS_HOME
./JENKINS_HOME/scriptler
./JENKINS_HOME/scriptler/scripts
./JENKINS_HOME/scriptler/scripts/.git
./JENKINS_HOME/scriptler/scripts/.git/... (skipped)
./JENKINS_HOME/scriptler/scripts/Sample.groovy
./JENKINS_HOME/... (skipped)
./README
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you cannot do that. The name `.git` is hard-coded in the source code: https://github.com/git/git/blob/fe9122a35213827348c521a16ffd0cf2652c4ac5/dir.c#L1260

Probably one way is to make a script which renames `.git` to something else and back before and after adding it into repo like

In working directory under `scripts`

```
mv .git hidden-git
```

In Dockerfile

```
RUN mv $JENKINS_HOME/scriptler/scripts/hidden-git     
$JENKINS_HOME/scriptler/scripts/.git
```

Alternatively, probably it's possible to pass `GIT_DIR` environment variable into the plugin, so it could use another name.

Comment: Would be good to change the behavier of that plugin. script probably is not so bad.

Comment: @LarryCai If I read this code correctly, it doesn't support GIT_DIR customisation... so no way you could do it unless modify the code. https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-server-plugin/blob/42393f76d7f5678f9ca49f8a76252be2cfa244c2/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/gitserver/FileBackedHttpGitRepository.java#L53
It should have `setGitDir` with some customisable value, but nothing here.

Comment: @LarryCai It's open source, you are welcome to introduce a patch.

Comment: could be. But I choose the script this time and update your answer directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
git add sub
git commit -m "add sub directory"
```

> I want to treat them as one git repo and push them remotely, but now the files under sub directory can not be included ?

They are not included because `test` sees repo `sub` [as nested git repo, and records only its gitlink, or SHA1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37608522/6309), and not its url as it would have if `sub` had been added as a submodule.

You would need to push `sub` to a remote url first, and then add it as submodule for `test` to see `sub` files.

```
 cd test
 git submodule add -- /url/to/sub
```

Or you would need [to use a subtree](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/05/the-power-of-git-subtree/)

```
cd test
git subtree --prefix sub /url/to/sub master --squash
```

Comment: thank, and the use case doesn't fit for this solution well