# How to solve this Git issue?

Tags: git

I see in the repo displayed on its web page:

[image: This is the problematic folder in my repo]

I can't pull it to my local computer, can't browse it, etc.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Is this a repository that someone else has created and you have cloned?

Comment: No, I created and I am the only one using it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)**, a [special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309) which records a SHA1.

It is typical of a nested git repo, which is ignored by the parent repo except for its root folder: the SHA1 of that nested git repo is recorded.

The problem is: the parent repo does not know from where this nested git repo comes from.
That is what a git *[submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)* adds: a remote repo url *in addition* of the gitlink (SHA1). That url is stored in a `.gitmodules` file. That way, a git clone --recursive knows how to populate those gray folders: it knows what to clone (url) and what to checkout (the SHA1 of the gitlink).

But here, you just have the SHA1, no url.

Comment: That means that I accidently had a nested git repo? And if I re-push it with a deleted sub-repo, that solves it?

Comment: @DoRe Exactly. Move your nested git repo, then do a `git rm -- classicthesis`, commit and push.

Comment: Well, at first it worked. I moved the nested repo, `git rm -- classicthesis` worked as well. Then I removed the `git` files in the classicthesis foldes, copied it back again and tried to commit them again.

I get the same problem again, though there are no git files left in classicthesis

Comment: @DoRe did you ad them before committing? Is there any `.git/` subfolder anywhere?

Comment: the ./git folder was somehow added automatically. removed it a second time and now it works. thank you