# How do I fetch/re-push a submodule in git?

Tags: git, bitbucket

In my git repository (Bitbucket) I have a reference to a sub project.

When I pushed it on the first place a .git/ folder was included (even though I use the repository only for backup so that'd not been really needed).

Now I have a **reference to that submodule** in the repository

```
 <folder_name> → <SHA> [<SHA>])
```

- When I do **git pull origin master** the folder if fetched but it's empty.
- When I try to put stuff in that folder (I removed it, then I pulled it from a different repository and then removed the .git/ folder to make it looks a normal folder, not a submodule) and then **git add . && git commit -m ".." && git push origin master** I only get **Everything's up-to-date** and of course nothing changed in the remote repository

**Goal**: push a past submodule as a normal folder part of the main repository.

**What I missing out? How do submodules work?** (the docs @ Github are not very clear to me)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I explained this morning in "[How to solve this Git issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37608522/6309)", this (ie '`<folder_name> → <SHA> [<SHA>]`') is *not* a submodule.

A submodule is composed of:

- a remote repo url (stored in a file called .gitmodules)
- a SHA1 recorded as a **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** ([special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309))

If you record only the SHA1, but not the url, you will have something like:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8JYH.png]

A `git clone --recursive` won't be able to clone the repo with that SHA1, because it does not know its url.

If you want to reference a subproject as a submodule:

- read [Git Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), and
- use `git submodule add https://...`

Comment: so basically that's just a folder I can't do anything anymore with?

Comment: also, what'd explain git diff is not showing any change despite I cloned another repository into my repository and made sure to remove the. git/ folder (so basically it should be seen as a normal folder)?

Comment: Yes, I explained in my previous answer how to get rid of it and replace it by an actual subfolders.