# Is there a way to download the zip file for a GitHub repository that includes links to other repositories?

Tags: github

There is a GitHub repository that I would like to download as a zip file. However, some of the code I want to download is located in separate repositories and only a link to those repositories are located in the main repository, not the actual code. If I want a zip file containing the whole codebase, do I need to download the separate repositories and assemble it, or is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly from GitHub: the tarball or archive representing a repo does not include its [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), assuming the repo has a `.gitmodules` file.

Only a `git clone --recursive` (maybe with `--depth=1`) would get you a *complete* content.

Note: if the repo does not have a `.gitmodules` file, [those references are just gitlinks to other repo SHA1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37613387/6309), without their URL, in which case even a regular clone would not get their content.

> If I want a zip file containing the whole codebase, do I need to download the separate repositories and assemble it?

Yes, ... except you might end up with the wrong content: the main parent repo does reference other repos specific SHA1, [so you need to make sure to query an archive for the right reference](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-archive-link).