# Visual Studio 2013, Git Cloning Issue

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2013, version-control

I'm trying to clone Git Repository using visual studio but I'm getting error.

Here is the screenshot of my error:
[image: Git Clone Error ScreenShot]

Please guide me to fix this issue and I need to clone git repository using Visual Studio.

Comment: Do you see any gitlink or submodule in your repo? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/37613387/6309)

Comment: This is not a VS2013 issue, it also happens with other GIt clients. Did you previsouly use this VS2013 instance? It looks like a fresh install. Do you have permissions to write to the folders you are checking out to? Can you chose a different location?

Comment: Yes, I have write permission and I try other locations too.

Comment: As a work-around have you tried [git clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) on the command line? It would help narrow down the issue to see if this is specific to Visual Studio or a Git problem. I also note (from the yellow warning triangle in your screenshot) that your login information in Visual Studio is stale. Try clicking the triangle and re-entering your credentials.

Comment: Try to create a new Git  repository and follow article below to clone it: http://www.malgreve.net/2014/06/17/cloning-getting-code-from-git-repository-to-visual-studio/

Comment: @Cece-MSFT, I can't create new Repo. I don't have accessed of it.

Comment: Where did your repo locate? In TFS or Github? You can create a new repo in a github or TFS, then under the Local Git Repositories section, click the Clone link and paste the link copied in the previous step.