# Github pages missing submodule?

Tags: github, github-pages

I followed the exact instructions (more than once) to make a github pages site, and I got an e-mail with this error

```
The page build failed with the following error:

The submodule `msgBored` was not properly initialized with a `.gitmodules` file.
```

The page it linked me to told me absolutely nothing about how to fix this, I am very new to Github, this is my first time attempting it. Thanks!

Comment: please see the answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441904/git-submodules-in-gitmodules-not-initialized

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't really tell me much. I already found that answer when doing my own searching. That answer is 3 years old and doesn't appear to work, as the answer doesn't really specify how to use the submodule add command.

Comment: @Treedot hopefully, I might still be of assistance 3 years after my old answer.

Comment: Ha, I didn't realize that was you. I ended up just upgrading to a real host rather than fooling around with Github. It may be good for some people, but it is really not user-friendly for beginners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mentioned in "[Page build failed: Missing submodule](https://help.github.com/articles/page-build-failed-missing-submodule/)".

You can see if the submodule initializes with:

```
cd /path/to/main/repo
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

But if you don't have any .gitmodules, then it actually is [a nested git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37875204/6309), and you would need to remove that entry before (if you really need it), add it as a proper submodule

```
 cd /path/to/main/repo
 git rm mysubmodule # no trailing slash
 git submodule add -- /url/to/submodule/remote/repo
```